# Is the ideal $(2,x+1)$ principal in $\mathfrak{o}_K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring

I'm trying to show (although I don't know if the statement is even correct) that the ideal $\mathfrak{p}_2$ is not principal, where

> $$\mathfrak{p}_2:=(2,x+1) \text{ in the ring of integers } \mathfrak{o}_K=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1),$$

where $K$ is the field generated over $\Bbb{Q}$ by a root of the polynomial $X^3-X^2+X+1$.

I supposed the contrary: if $(2,x+1) = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathfrak{o}_K$, then $\alpha \mid 2$ and $\alpha \mid x+1$, so there exists $\beta, \gamma \in \mathfrak{o}_K$ such that 
$$2 = \alpha \cdot \beta;$$
$$x+1 = \alpha \cdot \gamma.$$

Taking the norms on both side we get that $N(\alpha)\mid 2$, since $N(2)=2^3=8$. I hoped i would have got a contradiction, but when I evaluated the norm of $x+1$ i got $N(x+1)=2$ since this value is the determinant of the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\1&1&-1\\0&1&2 \end{pmatrix},$$
which is the matrix of the linear map which multiplies all the elements of the basis of $\mathfrak{o}_K$ by $x+1$. So no contradiction as desired (or better, not yet).

Other ideas I had did not lead to any results, unfortunately. Could someone kindly give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ You have that $\,(2,x\!+\!1)\supseteq (x\!+\!1)\,$ both have norm $= 2\,$ hence $\,\ldots$

Or, directly $\ f(-1) = -2\,$ so $\,f = (x\!+\!1)g - 2,\,$ so $\,{\rm mod}\ f\!:\ (x\!+\!1)g\equiv 2,\,$ i.e. $\,x\!+\!1\mid 2\ \ $

Comment: I know that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal with a factor $\mathfrak{c}$ other than $\mathfrak{a}$, then $N\mathfrak{c} < N \mathfrak{a}$, because the norm is multiplicative and $N\mathfrak{c} >1$. So, since both $(2,x+1)$ and $(x+1)$ have norm $2$ they must be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, that argument works if you know that it is Dedekind.